# Correct way to package a .ipynb as an executable file

Tags: python, executable

**Background** - I have created a Python script that has many dependencies; the script calls an API, returns some data as a JSON, before its saved in a pandas `df` and then written to an .xlsx file using `xlsxwriter`.

**Issue** - the script is written in Jupyter Lab and therefore is currently a `.ipynb` file. I am trying to turn this script into the most effective executional script, which I can run daily (using `Windows Scheduler`). In JupyterLab, I have tried to File --> Save and Export Notebook As...'. and that works if the script is simple, like `input("Type something")`.

However if I try and save a more complex script with many dependencies in the same way, the 'executable file' will open then quickly close, without giving me the opportunity to see what went wrong (the script runs fine in JupyterLab in `.ipbny` format) I should say that 'complex script' has a progress bar and other elements which should print to the console for an extended period of time.

**Help** - what is the correct way to make larger python scripts (with lots of dependencies) executable? And are there additional steps taken, when dealing with large scripts? Here are the dependencies that my code replies on -

```
# Importing depedencies
from configparser import ConfigParser
import datetime as date
import datetime as dt
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import requests as requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import time
import json
import jsonpath_ng as jp
import xlsxwriter
import enlighten
```

Comment: A lot of your 'Help' section depends on a lot of factors and 'correct way' is always very subjective. How large is large? Your level of comfort with Python and other components in a typical toolchain? And your title of 'Correct way to package a .ipynb as an executable file' is already leaning in one direction. You could convert your script to pure python. Usually you can get close with tools like Jupytext but usually you have to handle the output differently. Your post makes it seem like actually want you want is to be able to run your notebook as it is if you could? Would that be sufficient?

Comment: If you'd like to be able to kick off and run the notebook from the command line, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/run-ipynb-on-a-remote-workstation-so-that-all-results-will-be-save-in-the-same-pynb/13340/2?u=fomightez). I guess though that would mean you need to see if you can use papermill, ploomber, jupytext, or jupyter nbconvert from your Windows scheduler. I don't know the answer to that myself as I don't work in a Windows system with that sort of stuff. I would think there's a way.

Comment: Could you share the script/command you're using to launch the notebook?
Here are a few initial thoughts...

* You can keep a command prompt open after execution with the `/k` option. e.g. `cmd.exe /k jupyter nbconvert --execute <notebook>`

* It could be that your notebook uses some relative paths... Maybe it saves the `.xlsx` file in the immediate directory or does not specify the full path. This would cause problems if the working dir is in a protected location like `C:\Windows\System32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is converting it to .py just using pyinstaller. That is the traditional way of doing it.

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

Copy the .exe where all your other files/dependencies are.

And add:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
   application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
elif __file__:
   application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Add the application_path to all your paths

Comment: are you sure it work for `.ipynb` file ? because to run jupyter notebook require a jupyter server running. I haven't test it yet but maybe we have to run the server separately alongside the `.exe` app.

Comment: You can convert . ipynb files to normal .py files though